# React App communicating with Go backend api

Tags: reactjs, go, kubernetes, dns

I have a frontend React application and a Go backend service as the API for the frontend. Both are Kubernetes services in the same namespace. How can I communicate with the Go backend service without having to use an external IP? I got it to work with an external ip, but, I can't get the fqdn to resolve correctly like it should. The frontend service is built from the `nginx:1.15.2-alpine` docker image. How can I get the frontend React app to communicate with the backend Go server?

Frontend service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ui
  namespace: client
  labels:
    app: ui
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app: ui
```

Frontend deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ui
  namespace: client
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ui
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ui
          image: #######
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
```

Backend service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: client
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8001
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
      name: http
  selector:
    app: api
```

Backend deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: client
  labels:
    name: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: ####
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8001
```

Comment: Share your service yamls

Comment: You should be able to access the service by their name. This is taken care by kunernetes dns

Comment: I added those to the question. I have tried with the service name and it doesn't work.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use the container port in the target port fields in services?

Comment: I added that and still nothing. I have base API endpoint for the Go server as `api.client:8001` in the React app. It is failing with the error: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

Comment: Share your deployment yamls as well

Comment: Added deployment yamls.

Comment: Unless your client is in the same domain as your cluster AND the domain as a whole was delegated to the DNS of your cluster, ofc the short name will not be resolved properly. As a side note: More often than not, running nginx as a reverse proxy inside a docker container holds no additional value when compared to an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The React application does not run in Kubernetes.**  Maybe you have a dev server running in Kubernetes, but it just serves up HTML and Javascript files to a browser running outside the cluster.  The application in the browser has no idea about this "Kubernetes" thing and can't resolve the Kubernetes-internal `...svc.cluster.local` hostnames; it needs a way to talk back to the cluster.

Since you have the backend configured as a NodePort type service, you can look up the backend's externally visible port, then configure the backend URL in the served browser application to be that port number on some node in your cluster.  This is a little bit messy and manual.

A better path is to configure an [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) so that, for example, `https://.../` serves your browser application and `https://.../api` goes to your back-end.  Then the backend URL can just be the bare path `/api`, and it will be interpreted with the same host name and scheme as the UI.

Comment: What would the `...` be inside `https://.../api`? I guess it's the external ip of the service resource, but does one have to change the external DNS record every time one redeploys the service then?

Comment: Usually you have some sort of DNS service that can point at your combined system, so that host name.  Kubernetes in general doesn't change things that don't need to be changed, so even if you `kubectl apply` your Service object again, the external host name or load balancer address usually won't change.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing after realizing the React app isn't running inside Kubernetes. I added an api.* subdomain to the ingress that redirects to the back end service.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with the yamls. First, in service yamls, the targetPort should be port numbers(integers) and not string. So, the updated config will be,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ui
  namespace: client
  labels:
    app: ui
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: ui
```

and

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: client
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8001
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8001
      name: http
  selector:
    app: api
```

After changing the targetPort in service yamls, I created a pod to do nslookup and it works as expected.

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/busybox.yaml
kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup api.client
```

produces the output

```
Defaulting container name to busybox.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/busybox -n default' to see all of the containers in this pod.
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      api.client
Address 1: 10.101.84.21 api.client.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Thise two yamls are identical

Comment: My bad, was pasting the deployment yamls, edited answer with service yamls. Thanks